# How do I check if an ISSN is properly registered at issn.org?

Tags: publishing, series

How do I check if an ISSN is properly registered with issn.org? I found a tip on wikipedia to try link like "http://www.worldcat.org/ISSN/1021-9749" to see if an ISSN is registered, but for the ISSN in question (2032-9393) the link does not return an entry. Does it mean that the ISSN is not registered?

Comment: This one? http://www.worldcat.org/title/pams-potpourri/oclc/20329393&referer=brief_results

Comment: nope, this one - http://icst.org/security-and-safety/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on their [guidelines for requesting an ISSN,](http://www.issn.org/files/issn/demander_issn/requesting_issn_english.pdf) I would try their contact email and ask for confirmation: issnic@issn.org . Let us know if that works :)

Comment: Thank you, they indeed answered, redirecting to Belgian branch, though:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an online ISSN checker: http://journal-index.org/ISSN-validator/

Answer (score 0):

ISSN validity can be checked manually by algorithm described here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number) or you can use automatic ISSN checker (http://neredataltics.org/asi/ISSN-validator/)